# Using jquery .load without a delay

Tags: jquery

I create div place holders in my html and store the url for fetching on the rel attribute, some of these urls are slower to load

when using the folowing code, the each loop waits for each load function to be done before moving along to the next one which make an html with 5 placeholders load pretty slow:

```
$("div[class=ajax_wrapper]").each(function() {
            $(this).load($(this).attr('rel'), function(content) {
                //alert(content);
            });     
        });
```

How can I make the different divs load asynchronously?

Comment: This is not default behavior. `.load` should be non-blocking (hence the callback) except if you have set your ajax calls to be synchronous. Provide a test case for further investigation.

Comment: +1 to idea of providing more code - load shouldn't be blocking. And just a quick tip - instead of `$("div[class=ajax_wrapper]")` you can use simply selector `$("div.ajax_wrapper")`.

Answer (score 0):

You use AJAX to load the contents of each div resulting into multiple parallel asynchronous requests and until those requests complete the content cannot be shown. You may try loading their contents directly on the server on the first request and send them as part of the initial HTML. If the contents had to change you could use AJAX to refresh only the div that need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$("div[class=ajax_wrapper]").load($(this).attr('rel'), function(content) {
            //alert(content);
        });     
});
```

Edit: in document.ready, of course, i.e. wrapped in:

```
$( function() { //code } );
```

Comment: Wouldn't it load the same content to all matched divs?

Comment: Well, no, since it takes a parameter from the 'rel' attribute of the div.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't work :] *this* isn't, in this case, refering to every div found by selector. It would be evaluated to variable in outer context.

Comment: yeah, it didn't work, I'm thinking of loading the different content in iframes and end it with a function that pushes the output to the parent window's appropriate div since some of the modules takes time to load and it keeps the entire page stuck waiting to load one by one